# connecting RTC DS1307 to ethernet shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, ethernet, rtc

What is the easiest way to mount DS1307 to ethernet shield?

I tried to do this:
https://learn.adafruit.com/ds1307-real-time-clock-breakout-board-kit/wiring-it-up

but my program just freezes when I try to read data from RTC. Is there any other ways to do it?

Code looks like this:

```
const int RTCpin2 = 2;
const int RTCpin3 = 3;

void setup() {
    pinMode(RTCpin2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(RTCpin3, OUTPUT);

    analogWrite(RTCpin2, LOW);
    analogWrite(RTCpin3, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
     // process RTC time
}
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with that code?

Comment: this is not the whole code, is bunch of other things too, so I need ethernet shield and then RTC mounter to it.

Comment: Yes, but what do you hope to achieve with that code that you have shown? What do you think it will do?

Comment: 5V to pin3, reading with pin2?

Comment: Nope, you couldn't be more wrong. I assume those pins are supposed to power the RTC? Well, first you are using the wrong pins, and secondly you are using the wrong functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that snippet of code is supposed to provide the +5Vand GND for powering the RTC module.  Well, there's two fundamental flaws with it:

1. Pins 2 and 3 are the DIGITAL pins, not the analog pins. Instead you want to be using pins A2 and A3.
2. analogWrite controls the PWM output on pins that support PWM. HIGH is 1, so analogWrite will be providing a 1/255 duty cycle PWM signal on that pin.

So to fix it:

1. Use pins A2 and A3 instead of 2 and 3
2. Use digitalWrite() instead of analogWrite().